# Exp. distributed r.v. as function on sample space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ denote the probability space upon which the exponentially distributed random variable $X (\omega)$ with $\omega\in\Omega$ is defined. Furthermore, let $E$ denote the space into which $X$ maps. Is it true that $\Omega = \left(0,\infty\right)$? And $E=\Omega$? And $X (\omega)=\omega$?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say what $\Omega$ is. But we can say $E=(0,\infty)$ (though it can be any bigger set with $X$ taking values outside this interval with probability $0$). We also can not write down $X(\omega)$.

Having said that we can construct an exponential random variable on $\Omega =(0,\infty)$ with an appropriate sigma algebra and a probability measure so that $X((\omega)=\omega$ defines  a random variable with the given exponential distribution.